# How can I cut value after point? I mean: double a = 4.33333333 I need print it like this: 4.33?

Tags: c#

first I want to apologize for my English, but I have one question: in the code below I want to cut some values after the point, so ho can I do it?  BUT *Without using any Built methods!*

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array = { 6, 2, 3, 2, 12, 1 };
    double arithmethicAverage;
    arithmethicAverage = ArithmethicAverage(array);
    Console.WriteLine($"Arithmetic average of array is: {arithmethicAverage} "); // ==> 4,333333333333333 but i need to print:-->  4,33
}

public static double ArithmethicAverage(int[] array)
{
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        result += array[i];
    }
    result /= array.Length;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `{arithmethicAverage:D2}` or `{arithmethicAverage:N2}`

Comment: Use Math.Round() method.

Comment: `Without using any Built methods!` what does this mean? What are you actually trying to do? You can specify how many digits to use while printing, with implicit rounding. You can round or truncate a `double` before printing, and even specify the round strategy. Asking to not use built-in methods sounds like homework. Which is a bit too vague to answer - division is built-in too. So is bit shifting and many math operations. Floating point instructions are built into the CPU

Comment: Oh. Sorry about that. He wants to not use any kind of methods like Math.Round() etc. Well, I guess he can look at the answer I am going to post.

Comment: Specify the [format in the interpolated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated): `Console.WriteLine($"Arithmetic average of array is: {arithmethicAverage:N2}");`

Comment: first comment is working, thank u very much.. how can i flag it to Correct answer?

Comment: I thought you wanted to do this without using any kind of built-in methods. Like ToString(), Math.Round() etc.

Comment: ToString() and formatting like { xyz:N2} in string are in build function. Answer was given by @cemahseri is without in built function as per question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same [format and precision speciriers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) you'd use in `ToString()` for example

```
{arithmethicAverage:N2}
```

You can specify a custom format string too :

```
{arithmethicAverage:0.00}
```

The precision specifier doesn't round :

> The precision specifier controls the number of digits in the string representation of a number. It does not round the number itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to show it you can use ToString() extension method like this :

```
arithmethicAverage.ToString("0.00")
```

For more information you can search about string formatters in C#.

Comment: Not the best solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the built-in methods, this is one of the solutions.

```cs
var a = 4.33333333d;
Console.WriteLine(a - a % 0.1);    // 4.3
Console.WriteLine(a - a % 0.01);   // 4.33
Console.WriteLine(a - a % 0.001);  // 4.333
Console.WriteLine(a - a % 0.0001); // 4.3333
```